# How can two vector fields have same flow but not be the same? Left and Right invariant Vector fields on Lie group

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $X^L$ be the unique left-invariant vector field (ie $((TL_g)_h X^L(h) = X^L(gh) $),

with $X^L(e) = X_0$ and $X^R$ the unique right-invariant vector field with $X^R(e) = X_0$.

We easily see that $X^L(g) = (TL_g)_e(X_0)$ and $X^R(g) = (TR_g)_e(X_0)$.

We also get (letting i denote the inversion map $i: g \mapsto g^{-1}$):
$$ X^L(h) = (TL_h)_eX_0 = (T(i\circ R_{h^{-1}}\circ i))_eX_0 = (T(i))_{h^{-1}}\circ(T(R_{h^{-1}}))_e \circ (T(i))_e X_0 $$
$$ = (T(i))_{h^{-1}}\circ(T(R_{h^{-1}}))_e (-X_0) = -(T(i))_{h^{-1}}\big(X^R(h^{-1})\big)  $$
$$= - (i_*)_{h^{-1}}X^R(h^{-1}) = -(i_*X^R)(i(h^{-1}))= - (i_*X^R)(h)  $$

Now comes the confusion:

How can $X^L$ and $X^R$ have the same flow?
In the lecture notes we defined exp:$ \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow G: X \mapsto \gamma_X(1) $
where $\gamma_X = \phi^t_{X^L}(e) = \phi^t_{X^R(e)}$ (and also $\gamma_X'(0) = X$).
But how can these two flows be the same in all directions from the identity if the vector fields are, as I showed in general (in the abelian case they are), not the same.

We also showed explicitly in our lecture that $\gamma$ is the flow of a left-invariant vector field iff it is the flow of a right-invariant one. I can symbolically understand the proof, but don't understand intuitively how that is possible.

Probably I have some error in my understanding.

Would be greatful for some enlightment!

Thanks!

Comment: The two fields are not the same on G but they may coincide along their integral curves that pass though $e$… (Those integral curves are $1$-parameter subgroups and, in particular, abelian)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I also just realized that they are abelian subgroups. (I don't know what 1-parameter subgroups are. Will check it out). I think I'm beginning to understand what's happening. That is actually a quite beautiful result. Let me sum up if I got it right: for every vector in $T_e\mathfrak{g}$  there are unique left and right invariant vector fields who coincide along their integral curve which forms an abelian subgroup.